# How to keep this format while deleting cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I would like to copy and paste the "Population" and "Area" columns from this [Wikipedia chart:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_California)

[image]

As can be seen, the area column contains both sq km and sq mi. This is a problem, because when I paste the columns into excell, each population cell gets two area cells:

[image]

How can I keep only the sq mi information for each state, and preferably delete the words "sq mi" from all the cells?

I have tried deleting the cells manually, but then I have to choose from "shift cells up, shift cells to the left, etc.", which messes it up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that cells in column A are merged and therefore we need to un-merge them so that you can delete the #2, #4 and #6 row (the ones that hold the sq km info).

Secondly, in order to get rid of the sq mi, simply use find and replace and replace the character with an empty field.

[Step by step .gif for the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK7dA.gif)